# Reliable scheduling with sidekiq

Tags: ruby, cron, sidekiq, sidetiq

I'm building a monitoring service similar to [pingdom](https://www.pingdom.com) but monitoring different aspects of a system and using [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) to queue the tasks which is working well. What I need to do is to schedule sending out pings every minute, rather than using a cron based system which would require spinning up a new ruby instance every minute I have gone down the route of using [sidetiq](https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq) (notice the different spelling with a "t") which uses sidekiq's own queue to schedule future tasks. This feels like a neat solution, however I am concerned this may not be the most reliable way of scheduling tasks? If there are issues with the system (as there inevitable will be at some point) will this method of scheduling tasks be less reliable than using a cron based method and why?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You are giving too short description of your system needs but I'll try to guess how it could be:

In the first place using sidekiq means that you'll also need an instance of redis and also means that you'll need a way to monitor the sidekiq process and restart it in case of failure and possibly redis server.

A method based on cron tasks will have fewer requirements therefore much less possibilities of failing.

cron has been around for a long time and it's battle tested and it's very very reliable, but has it's drawbacks too.

Said that, you can build a system with separate instances of redis in a master/slave configuration and you can also use Redis sentinel to implement a failover in case of the master failure, implement a monitoring/alerting system on this setup (you can use something super simple like this http://contribsys.com/inspeqtor/ from the sidekiq author) and you can also start several instances of sidekiq in different machines.

With all of that, you can have a quite reliable system for running sidekiq with sidetiq.

Hope it helps